# MySQL: why inner join works and not outer join in the same syntax

Tags: mysql, sql-server, join

I have a table as below, and I would like to get US and France sales by date. For this scenario, inner join doesn't work.

My question is why `inner join` works in the query not `outer join`

query is:

```
select * from 
(select * from country_sales where country ='US') a
inner join
(select * from country_sales where country ='FR') f
on a.dateid = f.dateid
```

However on using  `outer join`, I get

```
Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax;
```

output should look like this:

Comment: Why do you need an inner or outer join at all?

Comment: And also `LEFT OUTER JOIN = LEFT JOIN` and `RIGHT OUTER JOIN = RIGHT JOIN`

Comment: what is `Full Join` ?

Comment: Generally the `FULL OUTER JOIN` OR `FULL JOIN`keyword returns all rows from the left table (table1) and from the right table (table2). By the way, `MySQL` doesn't have `FULL JOIN` feature.

Comment: then, how do I get the above output? if `Full Join` is not to my rescue?

Comment: why do you think you need `FULL JOIN` for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can USE `GROUP BY` along with `CASE WHEN`

```
SELECT 
dateid,
MAX(CASE WHEN country = 'US' THEN amt ELSE 0 END) us_sales,
MAX(CASE WHEN country = 'FR' THEN amt ELSE 0 END) fr_sales
FROM country_sales
GROUP BY dateid;
```

Please check the [**DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c9856d/1/0)